# Get version for rpm spec from yml file in project

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

I have a project in our gitlab, where there is a file in the /apps/app/config/version.yml with the version tag from gitlab is. 
Is there a way to use this file which looks like this:

```
parameters:
    version: v3.1.5
```

in the Version section from the rpm, so these two are the same?
Or if it could be obtained by doing a git describe --tags in the spec file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The rpmbuild parser usually uses the name-version as part of the path where the source archive (with the file that holds the version) is to be unpacked, creating a chicken <-> egg problem to determine the version from a file in the archive.